# How could I get inventory quantity for Shopify Mobile App

Tags: api, shopify

I am implementing Shopify to Android and IOS but I only see the `isAvailable()`
method for product variant but no Inventory Quantity.

I see it's available for web but no API for mobile.

Please give me some advices.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot get it without trying to create a checkout. If you create a checkout with too many items, Shopify will return you an error with the available quantity. You have to handle this error to display a message to the customer.

```
Client.createCheckout(checkout) { rtrndCheckout, error -> Void in
                    if (error == nil) {
                        // do your stuff
                    }
                    else {
                        // handle error
                        NSLog("Error Checkout \(error!.userInfo)")
                        if (error.code == 422) { //not_enough_in_stock

                        }
                    }
```

You can get all the data you want from the error object : inventory quantity etc... I know it's not ideal but it's the only way.